# How to remove entity with first level cache and JPA in one open session?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my persistence layer i have `remove` method that will remove the entities in removed state and `EntitySession` to commit the changes.

- The `EntitySession`

```html
transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
```

- The remove method

```
    public BehindCacheBuilder<R, V> remove(Object object) {
        entityManager.remove(object);
        return this;
    }
```

- And committing the transaction

```html
transaction.commit();
```

But when i execute the method nothing will remove from datasource.

Comment: Are you looking for changes in the DB after the remove call or after the transaction commit is called? Make sure your session has the same EM as the remove method and try calling em.flush() in remove. JPA can delay statements going to the DB until they are needed, allowing it to reorder and minimize the statements required, and implement batch writing and other optimizations behind the scenes. The only requirements are that the context is synchronized to the DB when the transaction is committed, the context is manually flushed, or certain queries that have particular flush modes set on them.

Answer (score 1):

Like any write-behind cache the Persistence context requires flushing (in your case committing, which is different than flushing) in order to synchronize the in-memory persistence state with underlying datasource.

Thus firstly make sure your entities that you want to remove be present in Managed state from first place then try to `remove` to change the state for delating the entity after flushing (committing) .

```html
    public BehindCacheBuilder<R, V> remove(Class<?> type, Object object) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(type, object));
        return this;
    }
```

Which in here we bring the entity that we want to remove to [Managed](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-hibernate-entity-state-transitions/) state.

[image]